# Pony ORM PostgreSQL Point type

Tags: ponyorm

Is it possible to create a data type for the geometric [point](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-geometric.html) type from postgres? For the point type, it is just a pair of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pony doesn't have native support for these exotic kind of types.
But you can specify sql_type like this:

```
b = Required(str, sql_type='point')
```

Which gives you SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE "A" (
  "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  "b" POINT NOT NULL
)
```

I just tested it in SQLite and transaction was succesful (even SQLite doesn't support point type). 
But you should do your personal workaround for validating `point` data you are sending to database.